# Compare results of Reduce

Tags: equation-solving

I have two systems of (polynomial) equations for the same positive real variables `a,b,c,d,e,f`.

Suppose that using `Reduce` I found that the first system's solution domain is given by

```
d1 = (a/b ==  c/d && e/f == c /d)
```

whereas the second systems' solution domain

```
d2 = (a/b ==  c/d && e/f == a /b)
```

(also `{a,b,c,d,e,f} > 0`).
It is obvious, that the two solution domains are the same. Now, I want Mathematica to compare `d1` and `d2` and tell me they are equal. How do I do that?

For instance: My naive attempt didnt work:

```
FullSimplify[d1 == d2, 
 Assumptions -> {a, b, c, d, e, f} > 0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Resolve[ForAll[{a,b,c,d,e,f},
   {a>0,b>0,c>0,d>0,e>0,f>0},Equivalent[d1,d2]]]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 2):

These must be the results from two systems not aware of each other preventing further simplification.

```
Reduce[d1] == Reduce[d2]
```

> True